# Update id after collection.create in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

On a collection, I am using the **create** function to save a new instance of a model to the server. This POST request is successful and I return the new model.

```
{id:135, type:tweet, start:08:00:00, end:14:00:00, text:foo, date:2013-04-01}
```

However, I need to update the collection with the new **model.id** that has been returned from the server and it appears that the **sync** method in **create** does not do this. Should I add a callback to the create function to update the model with it's changed attributes?

```
var AddScheduleBlock = Backbone.View.extend({
    saveScheduleBlock: function (ev){ 
        var text = "foo"

        this.model.set({
            text: text
        });

        var block = blockCollection.create(this.model, {
                silent: true,
                wait: true
            });
});
```

Comment: How are you getting the model id on collection.create? Im creating a new model but im not getting the id attribute back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone's Collection `create` method calls Model `save` method underneath ([code reference](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-108)). You don't need to set the id yourself, Backbone does that for you.

The Model `save` method sets the response attributes into the model ([code reference](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-62))

If the create is not doing the job, you should try debugging it.

Comment: A VERY stupid mistake here, my RESTful server was returning the model enclosed in an array instead of the object itself. Thanks for the help though.